# Faster Datagrid Highlighting

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am wondering if anyone has found a faster method for highlighting datagridview rows apart from looping through each row like so:

```
For each row As DataGridViewRow in dgTest
    For each cell As DataGridViewCell in town.Cells
        If cell.ColumnIndex = n then
            If cell.Value = "string" then row.DefaultCellStyle = highlighted
            End If 
        End If
    Next
Next
```

I apologize for the odd formatting. I am using a phone to type this out.

The DataGridView is double buffered and is bound but I do not believe that matters. I am unsure what other context might be needed. Apologies if I forgot anything important. I will give whatever context I might be failing to provide if asked. Thank you for reading.

Quick edit: I am asking because the amount of data displaying in the DataGridView is large. For smaller amounts I know this is good enough.

Secondary edit: I should have mentioned I have also tried:

```
For each row As DataGridViewRow in dgTest
    If row.Cells("Status").Value = "some string" then
        row.DefaultCellStyle = highlighted
    End If
Next
```

Comment: If you are only wanting to look for the cell at column `n`… they why loop through all the cells in the row? Use one loop through the rows and simply check the cell at column `n`. Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: I attempted that method as well immediately after trying the nested loop but saw no difference in speed. I used this example of the two because I thought it would be the most common of the two solutions. I suppose I should have added both to the original post. I will do so after I post this.

Comment: When you need to define the aspect of Rows or Cells based on conditions, you handle the related events, e.g., RowPrePaint / RowPostPaint for the Rows, CellPainting / CellFormatting etc. for the Cells. -- In your case, you could handle RowPrePaint and add a condition. For example: `if n >= 0 AndAlso dgTest(n, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString() = "some string") then dgTest.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.[Some Color] end if` -- When you change the conditions, `n` or the string value, invalidate the DGV (to apply the change immediately). No loops.

Comment: Generally you will find working on the underlying data collection your grid is bound too faster than anything in the UI.  Perhaps you could add a property to the collection class to indicate if the row should be highlighted or not that can be bound?

Comment: Thank you both these are very helpful answers. I am not at my computer for the rest of the day but I will try this tomorrow morning and post the results or any further questions.